# Why does the JVM of these Tomcat servers perform a full GC hourly?

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection, jvm

We run many Tomcat servers and have observed full garbage collections (GCs) are often performed on an hourly basis, particularly when memory usage is relatively low. The precise time appears to be relative to the time the application server was started; if a server is started at 01:13, a full GC is done at 02:13, and the next full GC will occur at 03:13. I haven't been able to find any documentation to explain this behavior.

This is a problem because a server pool started simultaneously all tend to do full GCs at around the same time. If the GC delay is long enough to cause a load-balancer to mark a server as down, the entire application can go offline for a time. It would be better if the full GCs could be distributed across a period so no two servers are doing a full GC at the same time, but I can't find any way to control this behavior.

Has anyone else seen this behavior? Is there any way to influence when these "regular" full GCs happen?

Comment: Do you have a process that runs on a schedule (via Quartz, et al.) that might fill up the heap on a regular basis?

Answer (score 25):

Your "regular" hourly GCs are probably due to [this known bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53267), "**The JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener causes a full GC every hour when gcDaemonProtection=true**".

Confirm your Tomcat versions and the value of the `gcDaemonProtection` property of your `JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener` (default is `true`).

The patch was purportedly included in Tomcat v.7.0.28+ and v.6.0.36+.

Either upgrade your server(s), or choose a non-upgrading solution from [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/201008.mbox/%3CAANLkTino=BjP5LsBCwncB2HvNDzyKLr5y-8yWdt15a89@mail.gmail.com%3E), summarized as:

1. suppress full garbage collections using JVM arg `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC`
2. keep the full GCs, but defer to the CMS collector using JVM arg
   `-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent`
3. set `<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"
   gcDaemonProtection="false"/>`
4. Disable the listener

Credit where credit is due; I obtained my initial answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916002/tomcat-garbage-collecting-frequency/14601304#14601304).

Comment: Gotta love the comment in the Tomcat Bugzilla entry for this issue:  _"By default, a full GC will now occur roughly every 290 million years."_ :)

Answer (score 3):

you should be able to change the interval by

```
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=60000
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=60000
```

take a look here
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19199-01/817-2180-10/pt_chap5.html

Comment: beat me to it... and here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/sunrmiproperties.html

Comment: Unless Tomcat or a webapp in it is doing RMI I don't see how this can make the slightest difference.

Comment: The link in the answer is dead. Wayback archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20130330063117/http://ehcache.org/documentation/operations/garbage-collection